# How do I stop Eevee videos from being pixelated?

Tags: eevee-render-engine, pixel-art

[image: Here are my render settings (i diddnt change much)]I'm rendering a short video using the Eevee renderer and when I view the video after its saved, it all looks pixelated. I can see whilst its rendering that each frame doesn't look pixelated when rendering. I don't know what to do to fix it
Ive got screenshots showing the pixelated effect and how it is supposed to look, and ive included my render settings
[image: Render looks pixelated when its viewed]

[image: This Clear Non pixelated screenshot is during the rendering process. Render isnt pixelated if its a still image but only when an animated video]

Comment: It’s hard to guess what’s going wrong. Could you share your render settings, a viewportscrrenshot and a screenshot while rendering and the finished result?

Comment: Has nothing to do with eevee, that's clearly a compression issue. Suggest render to an image sequence (preferably OpenEXR) and compile the sequence into a movie clip using ffmpeg, davinci resolve or whatever afterwards.

Comment: You don't show the settings for encoding, so it is hard to help you further.